# Docker: running application with a remote X-server

Tags: docker, x11, xvfb

I currently run my application in a container together with Xvfb and X11VNC. This all works nicely and I can see the GUI via any VNC client.
However, I would like to run Xvfb and X11VNC in container A, and my application in container B.

Container A is started as e.g.
docker run -it --rm --name x11  -p 6000-6100:6000-6100 myimagewithXvfb

In B I set to DISPLAY=A, to point to the X server (XVfb) in container A.

In B I start e.g. xeyes, but I get the error:
root@a1ec4b67e98f:/# xeyes
Error: Can't open display: 10.1.0.1
root@a1ec4b67e98f:/# echo $DISPLAY
10.1.0.1

Also using 10.1.0.1:0  does not matter.

Anyway, the question is how to get this to work, if possible at all  ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to tell for sure, but my guess is that your problem is related to X authority.  You can either allow clients to connect without access control by using the xhost command:

```
A> xhost +
B> export DISPLAY=10.1.0.1:0
B> xeyes
```

A more secure way is on container A ssh to container B like this:

```
A> ssh -Y B
B> xeyes
```

(Here you don't need to manually set the DISPLAY env. variable as it's set by SSH automatically.)

Comment: The xhost + solved it.
Although ensure it is done AFTER x11vnc has started.